# Validación de formulario instantáneo con jQuery

Tags: jquery, formularios

Necesito resolver un pequeño problema. Antes que nada, el código funciona, la duda es que en los campos de *password*, si yo modifico la contraseña ya habiendo ingresado la confirmación de la contraseña, crea un bug y no actualiza el mensaje del error de la confirmación de la contraseña. Yo creo que se puede deber a que estoy utilizando la función `keyup`, ¿Cuál debería usar o me recomendarían para mejorar el código?.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 function validInput(input){
    var type = $(input).attr('type');
    var id = $(input).attr('id');
    var error=false;
    var msg= "";
    var str_e = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$/;
    if(id === "name"){
        if (input.val().length === 0) {
        error=true;
        msg= "Porfavor ingresa un nombre";
        }else if(input.val().length > 30){
        error=true;
        msg= "El nombre es muy largo";
        }
    }else if(id === "lastname"){
        if (input.val().length === 0) {
        error=true;
        msg= "Porfavor ingresa un apellido";
        }
    }else if(id === "pass"){
        if (input.val().length === 0){
        error=true;
        msg= "Porfavor ingresa una contraseña";
        }
    }else if(id === "pass2"){
        if (input.val() !== $('#pass').val()){
        error=true;
        msg= "Las contraseña no coinciden";
        }
    }else if(id === "email"){
        if (input.val() === 0 || !str_e.test(input.val())) {
        error = true;
        msg = "Corre electrónico invalido.";
        }
    }

    if (error=== true) {
        input.removeClass().addClass('error-input');
        input.next().removeClass().addClass("error");
        var next = input.next('.error');
        $(next).children(".msg").text(msg);
    }else{
        
        input.removeClass().addClass('succes-input');
        input.next().removeClass().addClass("succes");
        var next = input.next('.succes');
        $(next).children(".msg").text();
    }
    return input;
    
}
 
 $('input').keyup(function(){
    validInput($(this));
 });
```

Comment: Bienvenido estimado! Tengo una consulta. El formulario va validando el password cada vez que haya un keyup en el password?

Comment: Sí, lo que sucede es que yo quiero que lo valide en tiempo real, el problema es, imagínese ya ingrese una contraseña dps ingreso la confirmacion y si coincide todo bien ok. pero si yo ahora modifico la contraseña, la confirmacion de la contraseña no se actualiza si no ingreso algo nuevo. No se si me explico bien perdon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No actualiza el mensaje dado que no verificas que sea igual o diferente con `pass2` , tal y como lo haces cuando el `id === "pass2"` , ahí validas que sea diferente con

```
if (input.val() !== $('#pass').val()){...}
```

Parecido debes hacer cuando el id es `pass` , además tomar en cuenta que cuando el id sea `pass2` , **`no se valida que no esté vacío el campo`**

```
else if(id === "pass"){
    if (input.val().length === 0){
    error=true;
    msg= "Porfavor ingresa una contraseña";
    }
    else if (input.val() !== $('#pass2').val()){
        error=true;
        msg= "Las contraseña no coinciden";
    }
}else if(id === "pass2"){
    if (input.val().length === 0){
    error=true;
    msg= "Porfavor ingresa una contraseña";
    }
    else if (input.val() !== $('#pass').val()){
    error=true;
    msg= "Las contraseña no coinciden";
    }
}
```

**Recomendación** :  **`Qué usar?`** , Una opción sería usar el Evento [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) para validar cada vez que se pierde el `Focus` de los `Input` , aunque el evento usado es válido si quieres hacer la validación en tiempo Real

```
$('input').focusout(function(){
    validInput($(this));
});
```

Comment: Acabo de actualizar con algunas imagenes, le quite el type password para poder verlo bien. Muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: @MarcosGin Mi respuesta deberia resolver su problema. Saludos.

Comment: Sì, solo usando el evento focusout, con el evento keyup seguria pasando lo mismo. Pero veo que el resultado no cambia mucho de todos modos le tengo que agregar el evento click y comprobar de nuevos los datos. Asi muchas gracias amigo!

Comment: Hola si, lo modifique asi if(id === "pass"){
    if (input.val().length === 0){
   error=true;
   msg= "Porfavor ingresa una contraseña";
    }else if($('#pass2').val().length !== 0){
    if (input.val() !== $('#pass2').val()){
         error=true;
         msg= "Las contraseña no coinciden";
      }
      }
   }else if(id === "pass2"){
    if (input.val().length === 0){
      error=true;
      msg= "Porfavor ingresa una contraseña";
      }else if (input.val() !== $('#pass').val()){
   error=true;
   msg= "Las contraseña no coinciden";
    }
   }

Comment: El problema persiste porque no lo verifica automaticamente, solo con el focusout se ve mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Solo estas actualizando en caso que no sean iguales, pero no colocas los demas casos, como lo es cuando esta vacio..

Vale decir:

```
else if(id === "pass2"){
    if (input.val() !== $('#pass').val()){
      error=true;
      msg= "Las contraseña no coinciden";
    }else if(input.val().length == 0){
      error=true;
      msg= "Porfavor ingresa una contraseña";
    }else{
      error=false;
      msg="";
    }
```

Comment: Acabo de actualizar con algunas imagenes, le quite el type password para poder verlo bien. Muchas gracias por responder.